# Case insensitive url-routing for Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-routing, case-insensitive

I am working with legacy code written in PHP 5.2.6 with Zend Framework 1.5.3 on CentOS 5.5

There is code as such

```
url:"./sales/getAlerts/?bypass=1"
```

The view is named getalerts.phtml

Controller function is named getAlertsAction

Code works fine on existing server, but when I try moving it to a new server the code fails stating that ...'Action "getalerts" does not exist...

If I change the lines mentioned above to make the [A] in Alerts lower case the code works.

I've copied over php.ini, httpd.conf, and .htaccess.  Not sure what else could allow case insensitive mapping to occur.

What is it that allows url-routing to be case insensitive?

Comment: id love to know the answer to this too. But ive always just kept the whole name of the action in lowercase to avoid this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use any URLs you want in your routes... I'm guessing you are using the default /:controller/:action/* route?  If so, create custom ones to point to the lower-case actions that you've defined.

The confusion lies in mapping your route parameters to your actual controllers/actions/modules.  Each 'word' is broken down into camelCase for the controller action, but everywhere else you have to use the hyphen to separate words.

test = testAction = test.phtml
test-something = testSomethingAction = test-something.phtml

You should be able to modify this behaviour.  Check out Zend_Controller_Dispatch_Abstract::formatActionName().  However, ideally, you'd just want to modify your route.

Comment: Thanks!  I found documentation stating somewhere between Zend 1.0 and 1.5 actions became case sensitive.  Started converting them all to lower case.

Answer (score 3):

Your URL: /sales/getAlerts/?bypass=1

Actually expands into:

- Controller: SalesController
- Action: getalertsAction
- View: sales/getalerts.phtml

The issue is you're naming your action method slightly wrong, so if the old/local server isn't case-sensitive (most PCs and Macs are case-insensitive) when tested locally it doesn't matter. When published to a webserver (likely UNIX) it's case-sensitive so it breaks.

What you actually want to do is keep all URLs lower-case and separate words with dashes.

If you use the URL: /sales/get-alerts/?bypass=1

It expands into:

- Controller: SalesController
- Action: getAlertsAction
- View: sales/get-alerts.phtml

While you can change this behaviour you're better off sticking to the ZF defaults with your naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in Zend, it's a good habit to name your action's function in lower case (apart from the 'A' of Action). (At least, that's what I do to avoid error)

The url can be with "getAlerts", Zend will search for the "getalertsAction" function in the controller.